# Add Middle Spacing Between the 4 Panes

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am learning html and css and I need to add spacing between each pane being displayed.  How would I do this?

I currently have the below code which creates two columns for me.  That's as advanced as I know how to get :)

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <canvas id="Top left"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <canvas id="Top right"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <canvas id="Bottom left"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <canvas id="Bottom right"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add **margin: 10px** of your **.column**. then you will get some space.

Comment: if I add margin: 10px to my column css then i loose my two columns.  Then it just shows each chart stacked on top of one another, appearing to be one column.

Comment: so, use the **padding:10px** of your **.column**. it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should try using padding and margin attribute of CSS and set margin-left=desired pixels and do the same with margin-right or use padding-right or left.I hope this answers your question